# Asset pipeline DEPRECATION WARNING tsort.rb:226

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have rails 4.2 working fine on development but in production env I have the following warning:

> `` DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226) ``

however I don't have config.serve_static_assets in my app config. It might be configured somewhere.

please help how to get rid of this. thanks in advance.

Comment: "The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` … Please migrate your configuration files accordingly." So do what it says. Go into your configuration files and change `serve_static_assets` to `serve_static_files`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deprecation warning you're getting is most probably caused by another gem that's setting that configuration for you.  For me, we're using [`rails_serve_static_assets`](https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets) and we're using version `0.0.2`.  To remove the deprecation warning, just update the gem (issue has been fixed in version `0.0.3`)

```
bundle update rails_serve_static_assets
```

Comment: For me it was not because of this gem, but `bundle update` solved the problem

Comment: hmm you should try to figure out which gems were updated when you ran `bundle update` and try only updating one gem at a time.  If that fixes the issue, add that as another answer.  That will most probably help other users.

Answer (score 6):

Open your environments file. (either `environments/production.rb`, `environments/development.rb`, `environments/test.rb`) depending on which environment you are in.

Change

```
config.serve_static_assets
```

to

```
config.serve_static_files
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and it seems a warning and not an error, and railties update automatically the **serve_static_assets** to **serve_static_files** as per the configuration file.

**Path:**
railties-4.2.7\lib\rails\application\configuration.rb

**Source code snippet:**

```
  # :nodoc:
  SERVE_STATIC_ASSETS_DEPRECATION_MESSAGE = <<-MSG.squish
    The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed
    to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables
    serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset
    pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0.
    Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.
  MSG

  def serve_static_assets
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn SERVE_STATIC_ASSETS_DEPRECATION_MESSAGE
    serve_static_files
  end

  def serve_static_assets=(value)
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn SERVE_STATIC_ASSETS_DEPRECATION_MESSAGE
    self.serve_static_files = value
  end
```