# Rails: Production assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline, production

I am trying to deploy my app on Heroku but I don't know why the bellow error occurs.

I have `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` so I don't use `config.serve_static_assets = true` and `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` as in the documentation explained that they are not needed in Rails 4.

When I execute these two commands respectively:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get this error.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.336814 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/font-awesome.min-1c15db9e10c99a36820b80616445a837a002b3f3969047f3375fba65f8fef2ba.css
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.337563 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/font-awesome.min-1c15db9e10c99a36820b80616445a837a002b3f3969047f3375fba65f8fef2ba.css.gz
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.341449 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/bootstrap.min-139ad6ac9cbd7b8cd15fa3f80b9b69e3ead570cb9686b3bb42b73a19ed62dcef.css
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.343432 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/bootstrap.min-139ad6ac9cbd7b8cd15fa3f80b9b69e3ead570cb9686b3bb42b73a19ed62dcef.css.gz
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.400914 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/jquery.fancybox-9eb4dcf39f4ad63c3bff3f55e2a0e5e8a32578cc4553c94633ce0ccdc08c2bea.css
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.401335 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/jquery.fancybox-9eb4dcf39f4ad63c3bff3f55e2a0e5e8a32578cc4553c94633ce0ccdc08c2bea.css.gz
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.405283 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/animate-0af100ee0144b8c4dc6de8605097b0920d4ea4aad067cc34fbaa7ab525d4e6a8.css
I, [2016-06-14T13:21:21.405707 #10455]  INFO -- : Writing /home/rails/Desktop/hammasir/public/assets/animate-0af100ee0144b8c4dc6de8605097b0920d4ea4aad067cc34fbaa7ab525d4e6a8.css.gz
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(sass):86
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I debugged and checked one of the files but I couldn't find any error like forgetting to use ), } or ; . Also, I cleaned the whole content of one of them and replace it by a simple CSS rule, but still I get the error!!

This error is also happening when I try to `push` my app to Heroku. Please, help me to understand what is the reason and its solution??

Comment: The error clearly shows " SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}" (sass):86 "
Check for syntax error in your css file There are multiple services which would do it for you [JigSaw](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), [Css Lint](http://csslint.net/)

Comment: @ChiragArya Using JigSaw, it produces many errors even for a well-known css file like bootstrap.css!!! It might be because of not supporting something like webkit.

Comment: It's clearly a issue of css syntax error if you remove your css file and then try to push your app to heroku it will work fine unless there's another error in any other css file. You need to figure that by yourself because without looking at your css file it's not possible to say what's wrong with your piece of code.

Comment: @ChiragArya Even by removing all of those css files from my app, I get this error!!:

rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(sass):86
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: `DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(sass):86
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile`

Comment: Maybe it's gems compatibility issue can you tell me your rails and saas version and your application.css

Comment: @ChiragArya Do you have any idea how can I find the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114630/discussion-between-chirag-arya-and-aboozar-rajabi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I found, wishing it to be useful for others, too.

To solve the DEPRECATION WARNING, update your gems as expressed by:

[Asset pipeline DEPRECATION WARNING tsort.rb:226](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812274/asset-pipeline-deprecation-warning-tsort-rb226/31151098?noredirect=1#comment63164244_31151098)

And about the main error, you should find which file causes the error exactly. The error output and mentioned files in it are misleading and not necessarily contain syntax error.

You can work with your `assets.rb` file to find which file (files) contains syntax error. Comment or remove all of the referred files in `assets.rb` except one, redo asset precompile command in your production mode:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and repeat it for all other css files to understand which one contains the error. This time the output of this command will be helpful and refer exactly to the problem. Then, it would be easy to find the error and fix it.